# Access the numbers in the object?

Tags: object

```
count = {'38,-88': 3,
  '39,-88': 3,
  '39,-87': 5,
  '40,-87': 4,
  '41,-87': 1,
  '38,-87': 4,};
```

I have many items in the object. i need to access those numbers after the colon (all of them to use a specific loop on the object)

i already tried dot and square brackets

Comment: Would you mind adding more context to this question? Which programming language is this about? It will help you get answers faster.

Comment: `for (var item in count) { console.log(count[item]); }` (JavaScript) or `for item in count:` `print(count[item])` (Python). Both worked for me after copying and pasting your "count" object. If this doesn't do what you intend, please edit your question to explain (examples would be helpful!) how the output you get differs from what you want.